# If $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability, does $1/X_n$ converge?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

is that true that if $X_n\to X$ in probability and all of them are $>0$ everywhere, then also $1/X_n \to 1/X$?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem

Comment: Your last 3 posts are all problem-statement questions. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: do you have a formal definition of convergence in probability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the proof for the more general statement: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem

I have the answer, why I cannot close the question? :-O